# AVAudioPlayer working fine in 5.0, issues in 4.0-4.3.5

Tags: ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have an app which plays and controls music across different ViewControllers. To do this, I created two instances of AVAudioPLayer in the app delegate's DidFinishLaunchingMethod:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"minnie1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *path1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
menuLoop =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path1 error:NULL];
[menuLoop setDelegate:self];  
menuLoop.numberOfLoops = -1;
[menuLoop play];


NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"minnie2" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *path3 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path2];
gameLoop=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path3 error:NULL];
gameLoop.numberOfLoops = -1;
[gameLoop setDelegate:self];
[gameLoop prepareToPlay];
```

After this I call it in various viewControllers, to stop or restart using code like:

```
- (IBAction)playGameLoop{

NSLog(@"Begin playGameLoop");
FPAppDelegate *app = (FPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if ([FPAVManager audioEnabled] == NO){
    //DO NOTHING   
}
else {
    if (app.gameLoop.playing ==YES ) {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
    else {  [app.gameLoop play];
    NSLog(@"End playGameLoop");
    }
    }
```

The audio files play fine the first time and they stop when asked to stop. Though, on iOS4 devices, they won't start replaying when called again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
Calling this method [stop] or allowing a sound to finish playing, 
undoes the setup performed upon calling the play or prepareToPlay 
methods.

The stop method does not reset the value of the currentTime property 
to 0. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call
play, playback resumes at the point where it left off.
```

Where you are looping the sounds, I would expect to be able to call `stop` and then call `play`. But I have fuzzy recollection of running into this myself. I found that calling `pause`, rather than `stop`, was a better solution. Especially since I could then call `play` again to resume play. Calling `stop` always seemed to require calling `prepareToPlay` again before calling `play`, at least in my experience.

It's possible that there were some changes in the API implemetation between iOS4.x and iOS5, too. You should check the API diffs on the Developer web site to be sure.

Comment: It seems I have solved this problem, at least on the one device I tested it on.

While it may not be the proper solution, it seems to work when I re-initialize the player from inside the new viewController.
I also listed menuLoop as a property in this viewController. Now it seems ok. Thanks All.